# Atomikos: data not getting saved when using PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, atomikos

I have encountered a strange issue while using [Atomikos](https://www.atomikos.com/).

I have a small test application (Spring + Hibernate). It uses two different data sources which I need to test [JTA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jta/index.html) functionality on a non Java EE container (Tomcat in my case).

When I use MySQL as a database everything gets saved without a problem. But when I switch to PostgreSQL data are not getting saved to the database.

What is interesting that IF I'm not using `@Transactional` and manually begin and commit transactions - everything works fine. But when using `@Transactional` - data are not getting saved. I can see that *hibernate_sequence* table DOES gets updated in the database (numbers are increased), and only the data itself is not. And all this despite the fact that I see in Atomikos logs that data was committed etc. Again the SAME code works fine with MySQL. This issue occurs only when using PostgreSQL.

I have tested it both on PostgreSQL version 9.4 (64bit on Linux) and 9.5 (64bit on Windows 10) and using different PostgreSQL JDBC [driver versions](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) (both JDBC4 and JDBC3).

Atomikos versions tested: *4.0.4* (latest as of now) and *3.9.3*.
Spring version: *4.0.9*.
Hibernate version: *3.6.10.Final*.

NOTE
I need those exact  Spring and Hibernate versions to emulate the working application I need Atomikos to integrate to.

---

#### Configuration and code samples

Here is my *spring.xml* configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.service.impl" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.servlet" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.entity" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.byteslounge.spring.tx.entity.TableOne</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.AtomikosJTATransactionFactory </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource1" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="DataSource1" />
        <property name="xaDataSource" ref="dataBase1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataBase1" class="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="user" value="tester1" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
        <property name="portNumber" value="5432" />
        <property name="databaseName" value="test_db1" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db1" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.byteslounge.spring.tx.entity.TableTwo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.transactionType">jta</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.AtomikosJTATransactionFactory </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate3.TransactionManagerLookup</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource2" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="DataSource2" />
        <property name="xaDataSource" ref="dataBase2" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataBase2" class="org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="user" value="tester2" />
        <property name="password" value="123456" />
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost" />
        <property name="portNumber" value="5432" />
        <property name="databaseName" value="test_db2" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db2" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Atomikos -->
    <bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp">
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="3000" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" depends-on="atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <!-- DAO -->
    <bean id="tableOneDao" class="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.dao.impl.TableOneDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="tableTwoDao" class="com.byteslounge.spring.tx.dao.impl.TableTwoDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory2" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is a code sample to illustrate how data is getting saved:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void persist(TableOne tableOne, TableTwo tableTwo) throws Exception {
    tableOneDao.save(tableOne);
    tableTwoDao.save(tableTwo);
}
```

And the DAO classes have the same logic for saving:

```java
@Service
public class TableOneDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements TableOneDao  {

    @Override
    public void save(TableOne tableOne) throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

            session.save(tableOne);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Could not save tableOne!", e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And hear are the logs I get when executing data saving logic:

```
13:48:58.521 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionManagerImp - createCompositeTransaction ( 10000 ): created new ROOT transaction with id 192.168.50.67.tm147946973850200001
13:48:58.605 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 14794697385
13:48:58.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.icatch.jta.Sync2Sync@57e48ad3 ) for transaction 192.168.50.67.tm147946973850200001
13:48:58.610 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext - successfully registered Synchronization
13:48:58.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
13:48:58.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
13:48:58.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'DataSource1': getConnection()...
13:48:58.612 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] INFO  com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean - AtomikosDataSoureBean 'DataSource1': init...
13:48:58.613 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
13:48:58.616 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - addParticipant ( XAResourceTransaction: 3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D313437393436393733383530323030303031:3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D31 ) for transaction 192.168.50.67.tm147946973850200001
13:48:58.616 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.start ( 3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D313437393436393733383530323030303031:3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D31 , XAResource.TMNOFLAGS ) on resource DataSource1 represented by XAResource instance org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection@7b57a36a
13:48:58.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy$JdbcRequeueSynchronization@ede1e016 ) for transaction 192.168.50.67.tm147946973850200001
13:48:58.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@2a39bdf5: calling prepareStatement(select nextval ('hibernate_sequence'))...
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator - Sequence identifier generated: BasicHolder[java.lang.Integer[43]]
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing JDBC connection
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@2a39bdf5: isClosed()...
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@2a39bdf5: calling getWarnings...
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@2a39bdf5: calling clearWarnings...
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy - atomikos connection proxy for Pooled connection wrapping physical connection org.postgresql.jdbc3g.Jdbc3gConnection@2a39bdf5: close()...
13:48:58.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.end ( 3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D313437393436393733383530323030303031:3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D31 , XAResource.TMSUCCESS ) on resource DataSource1 represented by XAResource instance org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection@7b57a36a
13:48:58.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener - generated identifier: 43, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator
13:48:58.638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.jta.Sync2Sync - beforeCompletion() called on Synchronization: org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl@3aa81ddb
13:48:58.638 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp - commit() done (by application) of transaction 192.168.50.67.tm147946973850200001
13:48:58.641 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction - XAResource.commit ( 3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D313437393436393733383530323030303031:3139322E3136382E35302E36372E746D31 , true ) on resource DataSource1 represented by XAResource instance org.postgresql.xa.PGXAConnection@7b57a36a
13:48:58.643 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG com.atomikos.icatch.jta.Sync2Sync - afterCompletion ( STATUS_COMMITTED ) called  on Synchronization: org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl@3aa81ddb
```

I have also set the [*max_prepared_transactions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-MAX-PREPARED-TRANSACTIONS) parameter in the *postgresql.conf* to be at least as large as the *max_connections* as it was recommended on the related Atomikos [documentation page](https://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/ConfiguringPostgreSQL) for PostgreSQL.

---

Again I want to emphasize that the **same code works fine with MySQL**. Only when configuring this web application to use PostgreSQL this strange issue occurs.

Anyone knows what might be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

OK, mystery is solved! It turned out that I needed explicitly call [***flush***()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush()) on the *session* object.

The following answer gave me a hint:
[Hibernate not saving Object in the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020631/814702)

---

### Example

Here is a working example (pay attention to `session.flush()` which must be called **before closing** a *session*):

```java
@Service
public class TableOneDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements TableOneDao  {

    @Override
    public void save(TableOne tableOne) throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

            session.save(tableOne);
            session.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Could not save tableOne!", e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And again, when using MySQL it works just fine *without* explicit flushing.

---

#### Interesting observation

The above mentioned test web application used pure *Hibernate* configuration and Hibernate's [*SessionFactory*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) (i.e. without *persistence.xml* and JPA *entityManager*). But I also have the same test application configured to use **JPA**. And in that application everything also works without explicit flushing both with MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: I had the same symptoms but within the Spring Boot application, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587328/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-no-transaction-is-in-progress/42591919#42591919) was my case.